# Difference between Windows Share Point Service and MOSS

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

What is difference between Windows Sharepoint Service and MOSS (Microsoft office Sharepoint). If I have the WSS 3.0 installed in my machine, I can create a sharepoint site, using Sharepoint Designer and Inforpath. Then why do I need MOSS 2007 (WSS 3.0 being free for download).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lot of the added functionality (and improvements, seemingly specifically with Search at least) are gained from MOSS2007. Have a nosey at the full feature comparison on the MS site for further details maybe.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePointtechnology/fx101758691033.aspx

Specifically, I think the Workflow and document management improvements are where you may get your 'wins' from. With a bit of a setup overhead initially, it can replace a number of otherwise complicated collaborative tasks which require a number of people.

Comment: Going to look at the feature comparison answers the list of differences - basically you need MOSS if you want to do something that WSS doesn't do...

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Services provides many features not included in WSS, some examples being Web Content Management (Publishing) and Enterprise Search.

Comment: SharePoint Services IS WSS. I'm guessing you mean MOSS there...

Answer (score 0):

MOSS also enables you to specify audiences for your lists. Which is quite useful in an enterprise environment.